# MongoDB ReplicaSet for Production Deployment with two Sites

Tags: mongodb, deployment, production

I have couple of questions with respect to Mongo DB production deployment.

1. Is using Mongo DB Replica-Set a right approach for a two site production deployment?
2. Can i achieve high availability with Mongo DB on a two site production deployment. I feel we need >= 3 data centers to achieve high availability.

Thanks

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes a replicaset is a good idea for a production deployment.

A 2 site / AZ replicaset could provide high availability, but replicasets need configured with an odd number of nodes (3,5,7 etc), so one site would always have a majority (i.e. one site would contain more nodes than the other).  If the site with the majority went down then the database would be unavailable.

Configuring the RS across 3 AZ would mean a better split of nodes and no one AZ would contain a majority.  This means 1 AZ could go down but the database would remain up.